# OpenGL Program Does Not Render

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, glsl, glfw

I have a Mac running OS X Yosemite with GLFW 3 and OpenGL 4.1. I've got this program:

```
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/string_cast.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "myglutils.hpp"

int main() {
    if (!setupGLFW()) return 1;
    setupApple();

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Perspective", 0, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create window.\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        return 0;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (!setupGLEW()) return 1;

    glClearColor(0.2, 0.0, 0.8, 1.0);

    const GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -1.0, -1.0,
         1.0, -1.0,
         0.0,  1.0
    };

    const GLchar* vert_shader =
    "#version 410 core\n"
    "in vec2 pos;"
    "uniform mat4 MVP;"
    "void main() {"
    "    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(pos, 0.0, 1.0);"
    "}";

    const GLchar* frag_shader =
    "#version 410 core\n"
    "out vec4 color;"
    "void main() {"
    "    color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);"
    "}";

    GLuint shader = getShader(vert_shader, frag_shader);

    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

    GLuint MVPID = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "MVP");

    glm::mat4 perspective = glm::perspective(45.0, 4.0 / 3.0, 0.1, 100.0);
    glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(4.0, 3.0, 3.0), glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
    glm::mat4 MVP = perspective * view;

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window) && glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glUseProgram(shader);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(MVPID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glDeleteProgram(shader);
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

The functions `setupGLFW()`, `setupApple()`, and `setupGLEW()` aren't the problem. Neither is `getShader()`. I feel like my error is something silly like forgetting a simple OpenGL function call. What I'm trying to do is draw a triangle at a 3D angle.

Note: this program compiles perfectly, but only displays an empty blue screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of issues in this code. The main one is that you never enable the vertex attribute array. You will need to add a `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` call in the setup code:

```
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

Also, the arguments to `glDrawArrays()` are not correct:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

The 3rd argument is the number of vertices. Since you only have 3 vertices, it should be:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

Also, unless this is taken care of in code you did not post, you need to make sure that the attribute location you are using matches the program. You use `0` in the code, but you can't count on the location being zero without any further action. The easiest way to fix this is to use a `location` layout qualifier in the shader code:

```
"layout(location=0) in vec2 pos;"
```

This will set the location to 0, matching your code.